# Попадание шарика в ячейку

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

```js
let roulette = document.getElementById('roulette');
let svg = document.getElementById('svg');
let count = +prompt('Введите число: ');

let rouletteLever;
let rouletteSpin;
let balls;
let runByButton;

class rouletteGame extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super('WorldGame');

    this.ellipse = {
      forBall: {
        ball: null,
        graphics: null,
        circle: null,
        hideTheBall: true
      }
    };

    this.boundsCoords = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: 20,
      height: 20
    }
  }

  changeRouletteSpin() {
    rouletteSpin = this.add.sprite(108, 110, 'rouletteSpin', 'Num_Spin_00359.png.webp');
    rouletteSpin.setScale(0.7);

    let rouletteSpinFrames = this.anims.generateFrameNames('rouletteSpin', {
      start: 358,
      end: 0,
      zeroPad: 5,
      prefix: 'Num_Spin_',
      suffix: '.png.webp'
    });

    this.anims.create({
      key: 'rouletteSpin',
      frames: rouletteSpinFrames,
      frameRate: 29,
      repeat: -1
    });
    rouletteSpin.anims.play('rouletteSpin');
  }

  changeRouletteLever() {
    rouletteLever = this.add.sprite(200, 150, 'rouletteLever', 'ColumnSpin_00089.png.webp').setScale(0.7);

    let rouletteLeverFrames = this.anims.generateFrameNames('rouletteLever', {
      start: 88,
      end: 0,
      zeroPad: 5,
      prefix: 'ColumnSpin_',
      suffix: '.png.webp'
    });

    this.anims.create({
      key: 'rouletteLever',
      frames: rouletteLeverFrames,
      frameRate: 29,
      repeat: -1
    });
    rouletteLever.anims.play('rouletteLever');
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.image('background', 'images/table_en.png.webp');
    this.load.image('wheel', 'images/UpperWheel.png.webp');
    this.load.image('ball', 'images/ball.png.webp');
    this.load.image('top-panel', 'images/3droulette_lobby_up_bar_full_wide_sdk.png.webp');
    this.load.multiatlas('rouletteSpin', 'images/roulette.json', 'images');
    this.load.multiatlas('rouletteLever', 'images/lever.json', 'images');
    this.load.spritesheet('button-deposit', 'images/button-deposit.png', {
      frameWidth: 180,
      frameHeight: 60
    });
  }

  create() {
    this.matter.world.setBounds(this.boundsCoords.x, this.boundsCoords.y, this.boundsCoords.width, this.boundsCoords.height, 1).disableGravity();

    this.ellipse.forBall.graphics = this.add.graphics({
      lineStyle: {
        width: 2,
        color: 0x00ff00
      },
      fillStyle: {
        color: 0xff0000
      }
    });
    this.time.advancedTiming = true;
    this.add.image(0, -160, 'background').setOrigin(0, 0).setScale(0.7);
    this.add.image(20, 30, 'wheel').setOrigin(0, 0).setScale(0.7);

    //Смена спрайтов колеса

    this.changeRouletteSpin();

    //Смена спрайтов столба

    this.changeRouletteLever();

    //Эллипс, по которому движется шарик, который должен упасть на ячейку

    this.ellipse.forBall.circle = new Phaser.Geom.Ellipse(260, 235, 380, 300);
    this.ellipse.forCells.path.point = this.add.image(-50, -50, 'ball').setScale(0.7);

    //Изображение самого шарика

    this.ellipse.forBall.ball = this.add.image(-50, -50, 'ball').setScale(0.7);
  }

  decreaseEllipseRadius(c, coeff = 0) {
    this.ellipse.forBall.circle.width -= (this.ellipse.forBall.circle.width / c + coeff);
    this.ellipse.forBall.circle.height -= (this.ellipse.forBall.circle.height / c + 0.2 + coeff);
  }

  update() {
    this.ellipse.forBall.graphics.clear();
    this.ellipse.forBall.circle.getPoint(this.ellipse.forCells.path.step, this.ellipse.forCells.path.point);
    this.ellipse.forBall.graphics.strokeEllipseShape(this.ellipse.forBall.circle, 64);
  }
}

let config = {
  type: Phaser.WEBGL,
  parent: 'roulette',
  physics: {
    default: 'matter',
    matter: {
      debug: true,
    },
    arcade: {
      gravity: {
        y: 0
      },
      debug: false,
    }
  },
  scale: {
    mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
    autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
    width: 1340,
    height: 760,
  },
  scene: rouletteGame
};

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);

document.querySelector('.roulette-spin').addEventListener('click', () => {
  runByButton = true;
});
```

Есть *рулетка* на **canvas**(понимаю, что скрин не самый лучший вариант, но по-другому никак):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Шарик* движется по внешней оболочке, и через некоторое время(задаётся) скатывается на *колесо с числами*(оно крутится), и останавливается. Само *колесо* - это целая картинка. Таких картинок в сумме 360. Единственное, чем они отличаются, это поворот картинки на 1 градус.

**Каким образом можно программно понять, в какую "ячейку" упал шарик?**

Возможно, необходимо разместить на каждой ячейке какой- то объект, к которому притягивать шарик. Но как сделать, чтобы эти объекты двигались синхронно с обновлением рулетки(колеса)? Пробовал двигать их по эллипсу, который бы совпадал с колесом, но не нашёл идеальной формулы(рано или поздно объекты, находящиеся на своих ячейках, начинают отставать от своих ячеек)

Comment: Лучше конечно дать ссылку, я полагаю поможет getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, а как это поможет? Этот метод же предоставляет данные о координатах. Но у меня немного другая ситуация - даже если я и у знаю координаты куда конкретно упал шарик, как понять какое число под ним?

Comment: я проглядел про canvas, сори

Comment: скормить нейросети

Comment: логически это выглядит так: 1) Вы знаете где находится центр рулетки, а так же ее радиус 2) Каждая ячейка имеет одинаковый размер/угол 3) Вы знаете в какой первоначальной позиции находится Зеро 4) Поворот осуществляется всегда на одинаковый угол.  Исходя из этих данных данных, Вы можете расчитать, местоположение каждой ячейки в любой момент времени

Comment: без кода , а еще лучше воспроизводимого примера, сложно что либо сказать

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, из кода только вёрстка на canvas) Ну и движение шарика по кругу

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко и тем не менее, хотелось бы видеть как выводятся картинки, как они отличаются, описание это отлично, но этого мало для понимания картины

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, код на фазере, ничего страшного?

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко думаю что не важно, хоть я с ним и не знаком

Comment: Phaser is not defined

Comment: А что если шарик будет всегда падать в одну и туже точку, а меняться будет только состояние рулетки в момент падения?

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/vYYmmxb?editors=0110

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, я видео эту работу. Но у меня совсем другое) Во-первых, колесо у меня вращается(тут статическое). Во-вторых, шарик только должен попасть на колесо(а тут уже на нём лежит)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, спасибо всем за ответы, но всё это было не то, что нужно)

Реализацию придумал сам:

**1)** Рисуем эллипс(внешний): на нём будет двигаться шарик, который мы должны приземлить на ячейку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2)** Рисуем внутренний эллипс: на нём будут расположены шарики, к которым нам надо примагнитить шарик, двигающийся по внешнему эллипсу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**3)** Как по мне, самое интересное) В какой момент начать уменьшать радиус так, чтобы приземляющийся шарик оказался ровно в своей ячейке, не затрагивая соседние?

Делим всё колесо на определённые "**секторы**", в моём случае - **квадраты**:
Их **схема** такая:

```
"0 1 2"
"3 4 5"
"6 7 8"
```

Мы должны начать "ронять" нужный нам шарик на ячейку только в том случае, если шарик находится, допустим, в 0 и 1 секторах, а нужная нам ячейка - в 4. И дальше по такому принципу... Но как узнать на какую величину уменьшать радиус? Для этого мне вполне подошла обычная теорема Пифагора:
находим расстояние между ячейкой(шариком на ней) и шарик, который нужно приземлить, как `Math.sqrt(a **2 + b ** 2), где a - расстояние по x между ними, а b - расстояние по y`. И уже от радиуса внешнего эллипса вычитаем эту величину(всё-таки придётся немного поковыряться с коэффициентами)

Для чего это нужно? Чтобы шарик не проскользил случайно по другим ячейкам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**4)** После того, как произошла коллизия 2 шариков, шарик, который упал на ячейку, скрываем. А тот, что уже лежал на ячейке, показываем)

Вот и всё :)

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите.

На сколько я помню, шарик вращается в противоположную сторону к колесу. Вот. Они вращаются. Но скорость вращения шарика падает, так как его тормозит колесо. Когда скорость шарика падает к некому минимуму, прикрепляем его к ближайшему обьекту, который тоже вращается вместе с колесом. Про этот обьект я как раз и написал, что он вращается не вокруг себя, а вокруг координаты центра колеса.

```
Если (получили_ячейку_с_сервера И ближе_всего_мы_к_нужной_ячейке){
    прикрепить_к_ячейке();
}
```

Comment: Читайте внимательнее) Я знаю как вращать шарик, я не знаю как приземлить его в нужное место

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко, ну да. Смотрите. На сколько я помню, шарик вращается в противоположную сторону к колесу. Вот. Они вращаются. Но скорость вращения шарика падает, так как его тормозит колесо. Когда скорость шарика падает к некому минимуму, прикрепляем его к ближайшему обьекту, который тоже вращается вместе с колесом. Про этот обьект я как раз и написал, что он вращается не вокруг себя, а вокруг координаты центра колеса.

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко, дайте ответ, чтоб я либо перенес этот комментарий в ответ либо думал дальше)

Comment: Решение не подходит, так как номер ячейки, на которую должен упасть шарик приходит с сервера. Моя вина, что не указал эти подробности...

Comment: Уффф. Тогда просто шарик скатывается тогда, когда будет ближе всего к нужному шкарику)

Answer (score 0):

Сильно палками не бить. Попытаюсь описать свой вариант решения.

Сделать 2 файла анимации: для шарика и для рулетки. В каждом из них кадров = количеству ячеек в рулетке или кратно этому количеству.

Осуществлять управление шариком и рулеткой путем смены кадров. Т.о. всегда можно четко указать на каком кадре (на какой ячейке рулетки) должен остановиться шарик. Для шарика та же процедура.
Принцип:
1) Запускаем анимации шарика и рулетки (с обычным ticktime)
2) Пока идет анимация, получаем значение выпавшей ячейки с сервера
3) После получения значения задаем по убывающей функции ticktime функцию обратного счета для анимаций (скорость кадров будет уменьшаться до 0).
4) Когда анимация остановится - шарик должен оказаться в нужной ячейке.

Там дело только за расчетом функции обратного счета от длительности анимации остановки рулетки.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно строить случайное перемещение шарика начиная от номера ячейки, пришедшего с сервера к стартовой позиции шарика (стартовый кадр анимации при рендеринге).

Т.е., чтобы правильно визуализировать, нужно всё просчитать в обратном порядке БЕЗ визуализации, а затем - запустить визуализацию (в прямом порядке) и шарик упадёт точно в нужное место (в нужную ячейку).